# Division in awk using variables

Tags: variables, awk, division

I am trying to perform an operation that looks something like:

```
 sd=0.206887
 mean=0.0195143
 awk '{print $2-$mean/$sd}' ABC.txt
```

However I am getting an error:

```
awk: (FILENAME=ABC.txt FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted
```

Would like to know the correct method to use a variable in this case,TIA

Comment: The shell doesn't perform variable substitution between single quotes, so the variables are never expanded. If the shell *did* perform substitution between single quotes, it still woudln't work, because the shell would take your `$2` as shell syntax and expand it, so that Awk would never see the `$2` syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
awk "{print \$2-$mean/$sd}" ABC.txt
```

Shell double quotes to allow substitution, with `$` escaped in `$2` so that it is passed through to Awk instead of interpreted by the shell.

Direct interpolation is a tricky way to pass variables to Awk. A less tricky way is to define variables as Awk variables using Awk's `-v` option:

```
awk -v foo=123 -v bar=str 'BEGIN { print foo, bar }'
```

Yet another way, the most transparent, is to use environment variables:

```
envvar=hey awk 'BEGIN { print ENVIRON["envvar"] }'
```

The reason this is more transparent is that the argument of `-v` is interpreted by Awk as Awk syntax. More precisely, as the syntax of the interior of a string literal:

```
$ echo 'foo\nbar'
foo\nbar

$ awk -v contains_newline='foo\nbar' 'BEGIN { print contains_newline }'
foo
bar

$ no_newline='foo\nbar' awk 'BEGIN { print ENVIRON["no_newline"] }'
foo\nbar
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `-v` flag:

```
 awk -v sd=0.206887 -v mean=0.0195143 '{print $2-mean/sd}' ABC.txt
```

*Type safety*:

```
awk -v sd=0.206887 -v mean=0.0195143 '{print ($2+0)-(mean+0)/(sd+0)}' ABC.txt
```

From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Options.html#Options)

> -v var=val
>
> --assign var=val
>
> Set the variable var to the value val before execution of the program begins.